video post creation api working but video is not posted on LinkedIn
I'm successfully making an API call to create a video post on LinkedIn and receiving a URN ID, but despite this, the post isn't appearing on LinkedIn. Text and image posts are working correctly, though. Could you assist me in troubleshooting this issue?
I monitored the API response but didn't encounter any errors. I verified the correctness of the API endpoints, and confirmed that the number of posts does not exceed the limit.

After a long effort, I finally was able to get the video sharing feature on LinkedIn to work.

Initialize Video Upload: LinkedIn API Documentation
$headers = [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->getAccessToken(),
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'LinkedIn-Version' => '202405',
    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version' => '2.0.0'
];

$params = [
    'initializeUploadRequest' => [
        'owner' => 'urn:li:organization:' . $author,
        'fileSizeBytes' => $fileSize,
        'uploadCaptions' => false,
        'uploadThumbnail' => false
    ]
];

$response = $this->post('rest/videos?action=initializeUpload', $params, 'https://api.linkedin.com/', $headers)->getBody();


Upload the Video: LinkedIn API Documentation
public function uploadVideoFile($filePath, $uploadInstructions)
{
    $fileHandler = fopen($filePath, 'r');
    $uploadPartIds = [];
    $client = new Client();

    foreach ($uploadInstructions as $instruction) {
        $chunkedUpload = $client->put($instruction['uploadUrl'], [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->getAccessToken(),
                'LinkedIn-Version' => '202405'
            ],
            'body' => fread($fileHandler, $instruction['lastByte'] - $instruction['firstByte']),
        ]);

        $uploadPartIds[] = $chunkedUpload->getHeader('ETag')[0];
    }

    return $uploadPartIds;
}


Finalize Upload: LinkedIn API Documentation
public function finalizeVideoUpload(string $videoUrn, array $uploadedPartIds, string $uploadToken = '')
{
    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->getAccessToken(),
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'LinkedIn-Version' => '202405',
        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version' => '2.0.0'
    ];

    $params = [
        'finalizeUploadRequest' => [
            'video' => $videoUrn,
            'uploadToken' => $uploadToken,
            'uploadedPartIds' => $uploadedPartIds
        ]
    ];

    $response = $this->post('rest/videos?action=finalizeUpload', $params, 'https://api.linkedin.com/', $headers);

    return $response->getBody();
}


Wait until video is uploaded: LinkedIn API Documentation
do {
    $videoStatus = $this->getVideoStatus($videoUrn);
    if ($videoStatus['status'] !== 'AVAILABLE') {
        sleep(5);
    }
} while ($videoStatus['status'] !== 'AVAILABLE');

public function getVideoStatus(string $videoUrn)
{
    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->getAccessToken(),
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'LinkedIn-Version' => '202405',
        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version' => '2.0.0'
    ];

    $endpoint = 'rest/videos/' . urlencode($videoUrn);
    $response = $this->get($endpoint, [], 'https://api.linkedin.com/', $headers);

    return $response->getBody();
}


Publish Your Video: LinkedIn API Documentation
$headers = [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->getAccessToken(),
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'LinkedIn-Version' => '202405',
    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version' => '2.0.0'
];
$videoUrn = str_replace(':video:', ':digitalmediaAsset:', $videoUrn);
$postData = [
    'author' => 'urn:li:organization:' . $author,
    'lifecycleState' => 'PUBLISHED',
    'specificContent' => [
        'com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent' => [
            'media' => [
                [
                    'media' => $videoUrn,
                    'status' => 'READY',
                    'title' => [
                        'attributes' => [],
                        'text' => $title
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'shareCommentary' => [
                'attributes' => [],
                'text' => $caption
            ],
            'shareMediaCategory' => 'VIDEO'
        ]
    ],
    'visibility' => [
        'com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility' => 'PUBLIC'
    ]
];
$response = $this->post('v2/ugcPosts', $postData, 'https://api.linkedin.com/', $headers)->getBody();



